# How to use a character string as direction to produce a data.frame?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I'm sure this is simple, but I didn't find a solution.
I want to put my string called Data

```
Data
[1] "as.numeric(dataset$a),as.numeric(dataset1$a)"
```

in function data.frame to create a dataframe. I try:

```
DB<-data.frame(Data)
```

but the output is my string. If I call DB the output infact is:

```
 Data
 1 as.numeric(dataset$a),as.numeric(dataset1$a)
```

not the values into dataset$a, dataset1$a.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Because I must change my dataframe then the string (for example dataset$a to dataset5$a) many times, I put a dglInput to choose the part of different name to put in the string, and I call it to create a dataframe. Sorry for my english, it is difficult to me explain better.

Comment: You should introduce the problem first rather, trying to get help with the solution. The way you are doing it now is wrong. There is for sure much better an easier way to achieve this without using `eval(parse(...`

Comment: Yes :) I found an another solution with the function paste0().

Answer (score 1):

Surely there is a better way to do whatever it is you want to do. But if you really want to run a string as if it were code you can use an `eval(parse(text = string))` construction. However, it is generally a bad way to write code. Nonetheless here is a solution:

```
# a test dataframe
df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
# string with code to run
string = "as.numeric(df$a),as.numeric(df$b)"
# split on , since those are separate lines of code
str = unlist(strsplit(string, ','))
# put it in a dataframe
df2 = data.frame(sapply(str, function(string) eval(parse(text = string))))
```